# Passing HTML to JSP include parameter

Tags: html, jsp

I'm trying to pass HTML to a JSP include directive parameter. Since the HTML I'm trying to pass has HTML tags, it interferes with the include directive parameter tags.

```
<jsp:include page="did-you-know.jsp" >
    <jsp:param name="content" value="Example: <a href="http://website.com">Link</a>" />
    <jsp:param name="source" value="None" />
</jsp:include>
```

Any way I can achieve this in a similar fashion to XML's `<![CDATA[...]]>`? Otherwise, what are my different options considering I use this include in various page, and that the parameters will sometimes contain plain text?

Comment: Just use single quotes around your url text.  value="Example: <a href='http://website.com'>Link</a>"